# Accessing and manipulating child elements in DOM by JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem in accessing my elements upon page loading.

I have simplified my code down to this but to no luck!

```
<div id="NavigationButtons">
  <p id="pagenum">
    10
  </p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function abi(){
  var page = document.getElementById("NavigationButtons").getElementById("pagenum");
}
```

I've tried different JSFiddle options like `onload`, `ondomready`, no wrap head, no wrap body...
I've also tried to write this in jQuery:

```
var p = ('#NavigationButtons > p#pagenum').text();
```

I am so mixed up between JS and jQuery.This is getting annoying.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do…?!!

Comment: This `'#NavigationButtons > p#pagenum'` is equal to `#pagenum`

Comment: it would be `var p = $('#NavigationButtons > p#pagenum').text()` for jQuery... You are missing the all-important `$` (or `jQuery` instead)

Comment: @Rajaprabhu: I know but I tried to be specific to eliminate the possibility of any mistakes...

Comment: @TrueBlueAssie: sorry that's just a typo... it's ok in actual code

Answer (score 1):

As I was saying in my comment, you are missing the all-important $ on your jQuery version:

**Basic test of selector:**

```
$(function(){
    var p = $('#NavigationButtons > p#pagenum').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

but you really need to hook up your button code from jQuery too:

```
$(function(){
    $('#abi').click(function() {
            var p = $('#NavigationButtons > p#pagenum').text();
            alert(p);
        });
});
```

and give your button an id:

```
<input id="abi" type="button"/>`
```

note: `$(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });`

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wK2FM/3/

*If you are going to use jQuery *at all* I would recommend forgetting that `getElementById` exists :)*

### Update:

As your item of interest already has an id you can simplify to:

```
$(function(){
    $('#abi').click(function() {
            var p = $('#pagenum').text();
            alert(p);
        });
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wK2FM/4/

### Notes about JavaScript version:

Javascript does not chain methods together the way jQuery does. `document.getElementById("NavigationButtons").getElementById("pagenum")` will never work. `getElementById` only exists on document, so trying to then call it again, on the DOM element returned from the first call, will give an error.

As your final target element has an id you could just do:

```
var page = document.getElementById("pagenum");
```

### Additions based on comment below:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wK2FM/5/

```
 // Does not work as text is not a property of a DIV element
 var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").text;   

 // This one actually works as innerHTML IS a property of a DIV (and of all HTML elements)
 var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").innerHTML; 

 // Does not work as value is not a property of a DIV element
 var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").value;
```

if you want sensible sounding methods to access properties, stick with jQuery. If you have to use *any* jQuery on a page, you might as well *do it all* with jQuery (as the code will be generally more readable and shorter than the same in RAW JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer TrueBlue :)
so why these doesn't work neither?
    var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").text;
    var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").innerHTML;
    var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").value;

Comment: Actually `var page=document.getElementById("pagenum").innerHTML;` does work. See update above, along with explanation.

Comment: great! this works. I'm confused why it didn't work for me earlier. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an element with id `#pagenum` you can do so directly as follows:

```
 var page = document.getElementById("pagenum");
```

or using jQuery

```
$('#pagenum')
```

Comment: IDK. I cannot vote yet! thanks for your help buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery you need to do very simply like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="abi(this)"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```
function abi(event){

$("#NavigationButtons p#pagenum").text()

}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TRZ8/)

But i will suggest you to write jquery event this way:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnAbi"/>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnAbi").click(function(){ 

   $("#NavigationButtons p#pagenum").text();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jQuery usind `.find()` :

```
function abi(){
var page = $("#NavigationButtons").find("#pagenum").text();
}
```

You can use descendent (like below), but find is faster than it.

jQuery with descendent selector :

```
function abi(){
    var page = $("#NavigationButtons #pagenum").text();
}
```

Result with find and descendent selector : [Link](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/38)

Comment: Why would you nest multiple `id` searches anyway as they are each unique :) Just go straight to `#pagenum`. That is the fastest.

Comment: yeah you are right, to find by id is fastest way. But as per question, he want to find child element inside specified parent... and he just posted the sample code and not actual.

Comment: @Sina Bizbone: I would hope the actual DIVs do not duplicate the IDs then, as this implies :) IDs should be unique on a page.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes, I meant multiple child <div>s :)